# SQL Server VIEW Performance

Tags: view, sql-server-2008-r2

If I have a VIEW with a bunch of INNER JOINs but I query against that VIEW SELECTing only columns that come from the main table, will SQL Server ignore the unnecessary joins in the VIEW while executing or do those joins still need to happen for some reason?

If it makes a different, this is on SQL Server 2008 R2. I know in either case that this is already not a great solution but but I'm attempting to find the lesser of 2 evils.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It *might* ignore the joins if they don't actually change the semantics. One example of this might be if you have a trusted foreign key constraint between the tables and you are only selecting columns from the referencing table ([See example 9 in this article](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/13-things-you-should-know-about-statistics-and-the-query-optimizer/)).

You would need to check the execution plan to be sure for your specific case.

Comment: Nice article, exactly what I was looking for, thanks. As you might have guess, given I'm asking this question in the first place, the FK relationships in this DB are virtually non-existent. Now I can see why the optimizer has basically no chance of helping me out in this scenario and my execution plan is suggesting the same.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't pull fields from those tables, it may be faster to use an `EXISTS` clause - this will also prevent duplicates from the `JOIN`ed table cause dupes in your results.

Answer (score 1):

Even if the optimizer ignores unnecessary joins you should just create another view to handle your particular case. Use and abuse of views (such as this case) can get out of hand and lead to obfuscation, confusion and very significant performance issues.

You might even consider refactoring the view that you're planning on using by having it join a set of "smaller" views to deliver the same data set that it does now... if it makes sense to do that of course.